# How can I get hundredths place instead of tenths place in output

Tags: swift, calculator, currency

When I enter an amount in the text field I get in total the amount in tenths place, so how can I get hundredths place instead of tenths place?
Also how can I get the tip percentage label an integer instead of a decimal?

```
import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController, SettingsDelegate {
//Inputs
@IBOutlet weak var amountTextField: UITextField!
//Labels
@IBOutlet weak var TipPercentageLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfPersonLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tipAmountLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var totalBillLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var billPerPersonLabel: UILabel!
//Slider & Stepper
@IBOutlet weak var tipSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var personsStepper: UIStepper!
//Variables
var tipPercentage : Double = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("DefaultTipRate") ?? 0.20
var numberOfPerson:Int = 1
let numberFormatter:NSNumberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tipAmountLabel.text = "$0.00"
    totalBillLabel.text = "Bill Total"
    billPerPersonLabel.text = "$0.00"
    numberOfPersonLabel.text = "1"
    self.amountTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    print("DefaultTipRate")
    let tipPercentage : Double = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("DefaultTipRate")
    TipPercentageLabel.text = self.numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(tipPercentage)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func setupContainer() {


    tipSlider.minimumValue = 0
    tipSlider.maximumValue = 100
    tipSlider.value = 20
    tipSlider.addTarget(self, action: "sliderTipChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    personsStepper.minimumValue = 1
    personsStepper.maximumValue = 30
    personsStepper.value = 1
    personsStepper.addTarget(self, action: "sliderPersonChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    amountTextField.text = ""

    refreshCalculation()

}
@IBAction func OnEditingFieldBill(sender: AnyObject) {
    refreshCalculation()
}
func refreshCalculation() {
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
    if let amount = numberFormatter.numberFromString(amountTextField.text!) as? Double {

        let tipAmount = amount * tipPercentage
        let totalBill = amount + tipAmount
        let billPerPerson = totalBill / Double(numberOfPerson)
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
        tipAmountLabel.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(tipAmount)
        totalBillLabel.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(totalBill)
        billPerPersonLabel.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(billPerPerson)

    } else {

        tipAmountLabel.text = "-"
        totalBillLabel.text = "-"
        billPerPersonLabel.text = "-"
    }

    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.PercentStyle
    numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    TipPercentageLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f%%", tipPercentage)

    numberOfPersonLabel.text = "\(numberOfPerson)"

}
@IBAction func sliderTipChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    tipPercentage = Double(round(tipSlider.value)) / 100
    refreshCalculation()
}
@IBAction func StepperPersonChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    numberOfPerson = Int(round(personsStepper.value))
    refreshCalculation()
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let SettingsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? SettingsViewController {
        SettingsViewController.delegate = self
        refreshCalculation()
    }
}
func tipPercentageChanged(newValue: Double) {
    TipPercentageLabel.text = "\(newValue)%"
    tipPercentage = newValue
    refreshCalculation()
}
```

**SETTINGS VIEW CODE**

```
import UIKit
protocol SettingsDelegate{
func tipPercentageChanged(newValue : Double)
}
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var tipControl: UISegmentedControl!
var tipRates:Double?
var destName : String!
var delegate :SettingsDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func changeValue(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    var tipRate = [0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25, 0.30]
    tipRates = (tipRate[tipControl.selectedSegmentIndex])
    delegate?.tipPercentageChanged(tipRates!); print("(tipRates)")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(tipRates!, forKey: "DefaultTipRate")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `NSNumberFormatter`, set `maximumFractionDigits` and `minimumFractionDigits` properties to `2`:

```
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2

let str = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(14.7)  // "14.70"
```

Alternatively, you could use the `String(format:)` constructor:

```
let str = String(format: "%.2f", 14.7) // "14.70"
```

---

For your tip percentage, since you are storing it as a decimal percentage, you can do:

```
let tipPercentage: Double = 0.17
TipPercentageLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f%%", tipPercentage * 100)  // "17%"
```

Comment: Thanks, so I had to create a constant let str?

Comment: Okay I will update my code here in the post, but I run the app and also the tip percentage is in hundredths place so what can I make another NSNumberFormater

Comment: I update my code above, I use String(format: "%.0f%%", tipPercentage) and when I use the tip slider the percent never change, it is always 0%

Comment: A lot of thanks it now works fine! Thank you for your help

Comment: hey @vacawama can you answer one more question please

Comment: How can I make the tip percentage sync with the tipPercentageLabel, I have a settings view where I select the Default Tip Percentage and I save that values in NSUserDefaults, how can I make that, I will update the code above with the settings view code

Comment: Yes I have a settings button in the main view and the settings view have a Segmented Control where I select the default tip rate for example , when I select a default tip rate for example 30% and go back to the main view and the tipPercentage label is updated with 30% but the slider is not synchronise, If i select 30% it supposed to be at the maximum.

Comment: thats in this line?     var tipPercentage : Double = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("DefaultTipRate") ?? 0.20

Comment: You have a routine called `tipPercentageChanged` that gets called on the `delegate`.  In there set the `tipSlider.value` to `100 * newValue` which is the value passed from your `SettingsViewController`.  There's no need to involve `NSUserDefaults`.  That's really just for app startup.

Comment: `100.0 * Float(newValue)`

Comment: Good night.  I once live in Ponce for a year.  Many years ago.

Comment: Ooh really! PR is nice, where did you live now?

Comment: Massachusetts, not far from Boston.  We do get a bit more snow than PR.

Comment: Buenos noches, Yadiel.

Comment: buenas noches @vacawama